# Producer Consumer module just outputting null

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I tried making a producer consumer Java program but it doesn't seem to be working: It just doesn't terminate, the terminal just stays like this: [image: this]
I want the code to print Text 1 then Text 2 then Text 3 all on new lines.
I want the write thread to write the text to print, then the read thread to actually print the text. My code is down below.
Also another question I have is when would this sort of model be used and is it worth learning at the moment as a beginner Java programmer. Thanks. Heres the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();
        new Thread(new ModelThreadWriter(model)).start();
        new Thread(new ModelThreadReader(model)).start();
        
    }
}

class Model {
    private String data;
    private boolean isEmpty = true;

    public synchronized void writeData(String data) {
        while (!isEmpty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            this.data = data;
            isEmpty = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized String readData() {
        while (isEmpty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        isEmpty = true;
        notifyAll();
        return data;
    }
}

class ModelThreadWriter implements Runnable {
    private Model model;

    public ModelThreadWriter(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String[] text = {
            "Text 1",
            "Text 2",
            "Text 3"
        };

        for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            model.writeData(text[i]);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        model.writeData("done");

        
    }
}

class ModelThreadReader implements Runnable {
    private Model model;

    public ModelThreadReader(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (String msg = model.readData(); !(msg == "done"); model.readData()) {
            System.out.println(msg);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try be more specific about your problem, `it doesn't seem to be working` doesn't tell us the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Also consider making `isEmpty` volatile

Comment: @BenAnderson Hi I haven't learned volatile yet, however this example of code I have written was based on something I learned from a video, I tried making my own version of what the lecturer made, I have compared the two and still don't know what is wrong with it. Do you notice anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: @BenAnderson Ive updated the question and added what happens when I run, thanks

Comment: What happens is the while loop in `writeData` never runs because `isEmpty` is true and therefore `!isEmpty` will always be false. You would think that this is changed by the code in `readData` by in actual fact the `wait()` call in `readData` pauses that thread and so `isEmpty` is never set to true. This results in `ModelThreadReader` getting stuck doing nothing and `ModelThreadWriter` never writes data because the while loop never runs. Not really sure on the solution to your problem though sorry.

Comment: @BenAnderson Ok, thanks for your help

Comment: @BenAnderson isEmpty is set to true when the read Thread executes the read method im pretty sure

Comment: All comments in my previous post were based on what I found when I rank your code and debugged it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

1.In `writeData` method, `this.data = data;isEmpty = false;notifyAll();` should move out of the while loop.

2.In `ModelThreadReader`, `==` => `equals`.

3.In `ModelThreadReader`, `for (String msg = model.readData(); !(msg == "done"); model.readData())` => `!(msg.equals("done")); msg = model.readData()`, otherwise it's going to print out `Text1` every time.

```
class Model {
    private String data;
    private boolean isEmpty = true;

    public synchronized void writeData(String data) {
        while (!isEmpty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        this.data = data;
        isEmpty = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized String readData() {
        while (isEmpty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        isEmpty = true;
        notifyAll();
        return this.data;
    }
}

class ModelThreadWriter implements Runnable {
    private Model model;

    public ModelThreadWriter(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String[] text = {
            "Text 1",
            "Text 2",
            "Text 3"
        };
        for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            model.writeData(text[i]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        model.writeData("done");
    }
}

class ModelThreadReader implements Runnable {
    private Model model;

    public ModelThreadReader(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String msg = model.readData();
        for (; !(msg.equals("done")); msg = model.readData()) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other problems, mentioned in the comments, above, the `for` loop in your `ModelThreadReader#run()` method will never terminate.

```java
for (String msg = model.readData(); !(msg == "done"); model.readData()) {
    ...
}
```

The `String msg` variable will be set to the result of calling `model.readData()` before the loop body is executed for the first time, but then it never will be set again.  Unless that first call happens to return `"done"`, the loop will not terminate.

Maybe you meant to do this?

`for (String msg=model.readData(); !(msg=="done");` **msg=**`model.readData())...`